# Female doctor wakes up in a destroyed village holding a child

Tags: story-identification, books

Trilogy where a woman doctor (I believe) is transported to another world and wakes up in a destroyed village and holding a child. If my memory is correct in the novel she uses magical stones also. She ends up traveling with the guy that finds her. I probably read it 4-5 years ago in the 2010-2011 timeframe.

Comment: Do you by any chance remember when you read it?

Comment: It's been a few years since I read it! Maybe 4 or 5 this is just a guess